# How to kill a single TCP connection in Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a process that opens several tcp connections to several browsers on separate ports.

Using netsat the output is something like this :

```
tcp 0 0 server1.something:myprog client1.something:49987 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 server1.something:myprog client1.something:65987 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 server1.something:myprog client1.something:89987 ESTABLISHED
```

Now i would like to kill exactly one of the connections? How do i do it? (Since killing the process will kill all connections)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some options:

- Attach with gdb and call close() on the fd. You can map from addr/port to inode number via /proc/net/tcp and from inode number to FD inside the process with ls -la /proc/$pid/fd.
- Spoof a RST packet. You'll need to generate it locally and guess the SEQ number somehow.
- Maybe setup an iptables rule to generate a RST on the next packet.
- Write a kernel module.

There doesn't seem to be a well supported way to do this. It is likely that processes will crash if their FDs are unexpectedly closed anyway.

Comment: I thing also the security thing is the main reason for the lack of such a tool

Answer (score 22):

On linux kernel >= 4.9 you can use the `ss` command from iproute2 with key `-K`

```
ss -K dst client1.something dport = 49987
```

the kernel have to be compiled with `CONFIG_INET_DIAG_DESTROY` option enabled.

Comment: Works fine on Fedora 36 (as root).

Answer (score 6):

You can kill by destination port:

```
ss -K dport = 65987
```

Comment: This solution requires root permissions.

Comment: @ks1322 Or more precisely, `CAP_NET_ADMIN`

Answer (score 4):

You can't kill a single connection of a process.

But you could block it with iptables. So the connection can't provide or receive data and the client will run in a timeout.